# Input Type not specific

Tags: jquery

I have the following part in my jQuery code:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click', function () {
```

But the problem is that I decided to use multiple radio buttons, so now, the system doesn't work anymore..

Does anyone has a solution to use the radio button for the jQuery wich I need? (For ex. use id="xx" or something like that) Thanks!

-Jérémy

Comment: please post your markup as well

Comment: `$('#xx').on('click', function () {`

Comment: @roXon - +1, even if that is so obvious that I'd be ashamed if I asked this question myself! If you can figure out an attributes starts with selector, you should be able to figure out an ID selector.

Comment: @adeneo I'm almost sure (kindly hope ;) ) that the OP has actually difficulties to explain what he exactly needs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple filters .. name for example or whatever you prefer.

```
$('input[type="radio"][name="group_2"]').on('click', function() {
    alert('Group 2 radio clicked !');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MPgzq/

Comment: Thanks, tried it with id, but that didn't work.. I'll test it now with name.. :) -- UPDATE: Works so far! Thank you so much ;).

Comment: `$(':radio[name="group_2"]')` looks simpler to me

Comment: Seems to work with ID too - http://jsfiddle.net/MPgzq/1/ . Also, what roXon said :D